# Why am I only getting the last item in the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my code I used for a payroll question seems to be missing something so that it calculates ALL users. I'm not sure if it's an indentation problem or not. I'm getting the last user but not the first 2.

```
file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")
print('\n%-15s%-10s%-10s' % ('Name', 'Hours', 'Total Pay'))
for line in open(file_name):
    line = line.strip()
    if line != '':
        (name, wage, hours) = line.split()
        wage = float(wage)
        hours = float(hours) 
        pay = wage * hours
print('%-15s%-10d%-10.2f' %(name,hours,pay))
```

```
Lambert 34 10.50
Osborne 22 6.25
Giacometti 5 100.70
```

My output:

```
Name           Hours     Total Pay 
Giacometti     100       503.50
```

Comment: The `print()` statement is outside the loop, so it only prints once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help in the future, please make a [mre]. In this case, most of the code is irrelevant and you could reproduce the same problem with something like `for n in range(3): m = float(n); print(m)`

Comment: Your print statement should be indented to the level of the if statement.   Please don't mark any answers as accepted, as they are only expanded versions of a single sentence answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's an indentation issue: the `print` statement needs to be "inside" the `for` loop. As you have it, the print statement is executed just once, after the `for`, using the values of the variables `name`, `hours`, `pay` computed in the last pass through the loop.

Edit: Even more precisely, the `print` statement should be inside the `if` statement within the `for` loop. You don't want to print anything if a line was just blank, and certainly you don't want to print the previously line again (which you would, using values from the previous iteration).

Answer (score 0):

Your `print()` is not indented correctly. It should be:

```py
for line in open(file_name):
    line = line.strip()
    if line != '':
        (name, wage, hours) = line.split()
        wage = float(wage)
        hours = float(hours) 
        pay = wage * hours
        print('%-15s%-10d%-10.2f' %(name,hours,pay))
```

The way it was before the for loop would take the wage, hours, name and pay for the employee in the current line in the file, then do the loop again replacing the old values. When the loop finished it would then print your variables which would contain the name, wage and hours of the last employee.

Edit: Btw, your print function should be inside the `if` because if it's only inside the `for` and you read an empty line it will print again the name, hours and pay of the last processed employee.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that helped. Always something simple. ughh